# How to dynamically drawline on Picturebox using parameter?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to determine the position of the line by passing on the parameter.

Below is my code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NormalVeiw = new PictureBox
    {
        Name = "NormalVeiw",
        Size = new Size(100, 100),
        Location = new Point(100, 100),
        Visible = true,
    };
    Controls.Add(NormalVeiw);
    size(0,0);
}

private void size(int p1, int p2)
{
    Graphics g = NormalVeiw.CreateGraphics();
    g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, new Point(p1, p2), new Point(100, 100));
    g.Dispose();
}
```

Is there any way to perform a DrawLine without a PaintEventArgs e?

Comment: I don't see a PaintEventArgs.  Otherwise, you should just use the PictureBox's Paint event and draw there.  CreateGraphics is a temporary canvas, easily erased.

Comment: What do you mean by "determine position of a line"?

Comment: @NoChance, Well... the positioning of the line means I want to deliver the value I want and drawline.

Comment: You are trying to paint in [Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load), where form is not yet shown. Using [Shown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown) *may* produce some output, but only until next paint. I suggest you to find tutorial explaining [painting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint) in winforms, so you can make it properly.

Comment: Well, is there a way to deliver parameters to PictureboxEvent?

Comment: If you need some extra information in the Paint Event then put those in class variables.

Comment: @Ralf , Modifying a class also has the problem of delivering PaintEventArgs. :(

Comment: Just store your line information in a class, if more than one line, a List<Class>, and loop through that in the paint event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Drawing;

private Point p1, p2;

public Form2()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  p1 = new Point(0, 0);
  p2 = new Point(150, 150);
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(e.ClipRectangle.X, e.ClipRectangle.Y, e.ClipRectangle.Width, e.ClipRectangle.Height);
  e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Green, 20), rect);
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), p1,p2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest case is to move your x,y values out to form level so they can be accessed from the paint event:

```
private int? p1, p2;
PictureBox NormalVeiw;        

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NormalVeiw = new PictureBox
    {
        Name = "NormalVeiw",
        Size = new Size(100, 100),
        Location = new Point(100, 100),
        Visible = true,
    };

    NormalVeiw.Paint += (s, pe) => {
        if (p1.HasValue && p2.HasValue)
        {
            pe.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, new Point(p1.Value, p2.Value), new Point(100, 100));
        }                
    };

    Controls.Add(NormalVeiw);

    size(0, 0);
}
```

Your `size()` method will simply update those x,y values and `Invalidate()` the PictureBox causing it to repaint itself:

```
private void size(int p1, int p2)
{
    this.p1 = p1;
    this.p2 = p2;
    NormalVeiw.Invalidate();
}
```

Now you can call `size()` with different values and the line will change.

If you need more than one line, then create some kind of structure/class to represent the information about that line, then store it in a `List<YourStructureHere>`.  In the paint event you'd iterate over that list and draw each line.